# Trabalhando com Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Como executar a tag:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost.com/web-p/index2.aspx"></iframe>
```

Esperando a execução do iframe completar o carregamento da página para prosseguir com outras coisas.

Exemplo:

```
function onIframeCompleto(){
    alert('o site carregou com sucesso!');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só usar o evento `onload` do `iframe`.

Exemplo:

```js
function onIframeCompleto() {
  alert('Site terminou de carregar.');
}
```

```html
<iframe src="http://example.org" onload="onIframeCompleto()"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta você utilizar o evento `onload` para o `iframe`.

Veja um exemplo:

```
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){

       var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe'),
           carregar = document.querySelector('#carregar');


        carregar.addEventListener('click', function()
        {
            // mudamos o src do iframe
            iframe.src = 'include.php?' + new Date()
        });

        iframe.addEventListener('load', function(){

            alert('carregou o conteúdo do iframe')
        })
    })
```

HTML:

```
 <iframe></iframe>
 <a href="#" id="carregar">Carregar</a>
```

Fiz o exemplo alterando o `src` do `iframe` posteriormente através do evento de click em `#carregar` para ele possa ficar mais perceptível no momento dos testes.